# Dynamically panning and zooming rGraph line chart using the mouse

Tags: rgraph

I am trying to avoid spending a lot of time to find out rGraph is incapable of doing what I need.
I need to be able to use my mouse to zoom and or pan the x and y axis.  I also need to be able to capture the subset of the original array that is selected so that I can make calculations on the set. 
Is rGraph capable of this?  If not is that another graphing tool might be capable, say D3?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of drill-down using the Scatter chart in the archive called:

```
demos/scatter-drilldown.html
```

But it does take a fair amount of code that isn't really super easy to follow (though compared to D3 you might find it a joy to get along with).

There's no zoom either.

You could also look at this demo too:

```
demos/line-static-yaxis.html
```

It doesn't do exactly what you've asked for - but is still worth a look.